# Error computing CMake server result in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

In Android Studio I'm getting the following error when attempting to build my project:

```
Error computing CMake server result.
Check for working C compiler: /Users/donturner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang
Check for working C compiler: /Users/donturner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/donturner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/donturner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Configuring done
```

What is causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 16):

Android Studio hides the root cause of this error pretty well. To find it you need to open the Build view (View->Tool windows->Build). Now click on the "Toggle windows" button which looks like this:

[image: Toggle view button]
You should now see the root cause of this problem. In my case it was:

> CMake Error at
>   /Users/donturner/Code/workspace-android/io-2019-sonic-boom/SonicBoomApp/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:4
>   (add_library):   Cannot find source file:
>
> ```
> src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
> ```
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
>   .hpp   .hxx .in .txx Failed to compute build system.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I had an incorrect path to my source file - an easy fix once you know what the problem is.

Comment: AS seems to hide a lot of stuff. This for one, but also the AAPT2 logs and periodically issues with Kotlin (my experience at least). Just seems like horrible design to me, especially because it suppresses the actual problem. It's definitively worth having this documented though

Comment: Using command line `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` will tell more information which might be *hidden* by IDE.

Comment: I filed https://issuetracker.google.com/133184474 to track making this stuff easier to see.

Comment: idk why they decided to hiding important information and just show us stupid error message.